# Find directories and files with permissions other than 775 / 664

Tags: permissions, find

I am moving a website from one server to another and Git does not store metadata such as file permissions. I need to find the directories and files that are not 775 / 664 respectively.

Right now, I'm using this cobbled-together contraption:

```
$ find . -type d -exec ls -la {} \; | grep ^d | grep -v ^drwxrwxr-x
$ find . -type f -exec ls -la {} \; | grep -v ^d | grep -v ^-rw-rw-r-- | grep -v '.git'
```

Though this works, I feel it is rather hacky. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps a canonical way, or should I just be hacky?

This is running on a recent Ubuntu version with GNU tools under Bash.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the [`-perm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Mode-Bits) test to `find` in combination with [`-not`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators):

```
find -type d -not -perm 775 -o -type f -not -perm 664
```

- `-perm 775` matches all files with permissions exactly equal to `775`. `-perm 664` does the same for `664`.
- `-not` (boolean NOT) negates the test that follows, so it matches exactly the opposite of what it would have: in this case, all those files that don't have the correct permissions.
- `-o` (boolean OR) combines two sets of tests together, matching when either of them do: it has the lowest precedence, so it divides our tests into two distinct groups. You can also [use parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators) to be more explicit. Here we match directories with permissions that are not `775` and ordinary files with permissions that are not `664`.

If you wanted two separate commands for directories and files, just cut it in half at `-o` and use each half separately:

```
find -type f -not -perm 664
find -type d -not -perm 775
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I did not know that two different conditions could be set (type -d and type -f for instance) nor did I know about -perm.

Comment: Maybe note that `-not` isn't a POSIX standard; they use `!` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea what your code was trying to achieve.
Normally the reason for finding Files and Directories with incorrect permissions is for the purpose of changing them.

So this is what I am successfully using in Ubuntu 16.04

```
find \! -perm 775 -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find \! -perm 664 -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

This demonstrates the ! symbol being escaped

Comment: In fact the goal was not to change the files' permissions but rather to identify which files need snowflake permissions when uploading them to a production webserver. Thanks.

Comment: "_snowflake permissions_"??

Comment: Contemporary use of "snowflake" can be attributed to the 1996 movie Fight Club, used in the phrase "beautiful and unique snowflake".  In the context of this post, it indicates those particular files which require, for whatever reason, atypical permissions.  Identifying and understanding such files is critical so that a blanket chmod -R or the like doesn't cause a disaster.  Strange permissions needed by strange programs are an absolute nightmare to troubleshoot.