# Script to find files less permissive than 750?

Tags: shell-script, files, permissions

I need to write a STIG rule that will check for all files within a user's home directory, and result in a 1 if any are found to be less permissive than 750.

This is what i have made so far.

```
egrep ":[0-9]{4}:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6 |
while read line; do
  if [ ! -e "${line}" ];then
    exit 1
  else
    if [ `stat -c "%a" "${line}"` -gt 750 ];then
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
done
```

However, this does not work when permissions are a number such as 557. I can't think of a way, at least with my skill level, to get this to work.

How would i check all files within a home directory, and have it return 1 if it finds a file that is less permissive than 750?

Example: 751,757, 551, 501, 001, 770, 570.. should all fail. My script does not capture all these.

**To Clarify:** I need to ensure NONE of the files in the home directory have ANY "other" attributes. If they have ethier r,w, or x in the "other", it needs to fail. Additionally, in the "group", it needs to only not have w. As long as it cant find any files where the "group" has write or the "other" has read, write, or execute, then it should pass. If it finds theses, it needs to fail.

If i could also modify this so that files owned from root are excluded, that would be helpful

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what you mean by "less permissive than 750", and also say in what way e.g. 001 and 751 is less permissive than 750.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144268/find-directories-and-files-with-permissions-other-than-775-664.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if any are found to be less permissive than 750

If the permission bits are `0750`, that corresponds to `rwxr-x---`. Anything that has e.g. bits set in the "other" group, is (basically by definition) more permissive. Similarly, something like `0700` is less permissive (it doesn't give any access to the group).

However, something like `0644` / `rw-r--r--` would be both more and less permissive, as it would allow read access to "others", but wouldn't allow execute access to anyone.

> To Clarify: I need to ensure NONE of the files in the home directory have ANY "other" attributes.

This, of course, is different than the above definition. But it's also easier to search for files that have some of a set of permissions bits set, so let's do this, instead of looking for files that have only a subset of some set of permissions bits.

Assuming you have GNU find, there's the condition `-perm /mode`, which means "Any of the permission bits *mode* are set for the file." (see [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)). So `find -type f -perm /027` would find any regular files that have any of the bits `----w-rwx` set. The similar condition in e.g. FreeBSD find is `-perm +027` ([man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1))).

So, perhaps something in this direction:

```
x=$(find "$dir" -type f -perm /027 -print -quit)
if [ "$x" != "" ]; then
    echo "some files were found"
fi
```