# Recursive chmod to 644 where current permission equals 755

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I copied a project directory to a portable hard disk, wiped my laptop and copied the project back, but now git reports loads of changes due to files that previously had 644 permission changing to 755.

I could recursively chmod all files and directories to 644, but then I get a load more changes in git (so looks like not everything was 644 previously). Is there any way to chmod only files that have 755 permissions?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Find directories and files with permissions other than 775 / 664](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144268/find-directories-and-files-with-permissions-other-than-775-664)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation for `find` (see `man find`) writes,

> **`-perm mode`** File's permission bits are exactly mode (octal or symbolic). [...] See the EXAMPLES section for some illustrative examples.

So you can match files and change their permissions like this

```
find path/to/files -type f -perm 0755 -exec echo chmod 0644 {} +
```

Remove the `echo` when you are comfortable that it's showing you what you expect, and run it again.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for this!

Comment: +1 for including the echo and instructions on its use for a dry run.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a git repository's worktree, just checking out the files should fix their permissions. I.e., do a `git checkout -f`.

Comment: Thanks for this and it's actually kind of what I did (I just moved my local files and re-cloned from the remote) but it felt like a bit of a cheat (it didn't really teach me anything) so I wanted to ask the question anyway so I know for future. Hopefully Google indexes this nicely and then it's a handy reference in future.